# Erro ao comparar datas vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

Fiz uma função para comparação de datas. Ela compara a data de um input com uma coluna de datas de um datatable. Segue o código:

```
    Public Shared Function GetNextDiaUtil(d As Date) As Date
            Dim feriados As DataTable = ManipulaDB.ConsultaSql("SELECT CAMPO2 FROM TAB_FERIADOS")
            If d.DaysOfWeek = DaysOfWeek.Saturday Then
                d = d.AddDays(2)
            ElseIf d.DayOfWeek = DaysOfWeek.Sunday Then
                d = d.AddDays(1)
            End If

            For Each data As DataRow In feriados.Rows
                If d.Equals(CDate(data.ToString)) Then
                    d = d.AddDays(1)
                End If
            Next
        Return d
    End Function
```

O seguinte erro é lançado: Conversion from string "System.Data.DataRow" to type 'Date' is not valid.
Se no lugar de `data.ToString` colocar uma string como `07-09-2021` é feita a comparação corretamente. Como comparo um type Date com um DataRow?

Comment: feriados.Rows eu acho que isso retorna uma coleção então não pode simplesmente dar um `toString` e também tem que verificar via debug o que tem dentro de `data`

Comment: o CAMPO2 é de qual tipo?

Comment: @novic o CAMPO2 é do tipo DATE no banco de dados.

Answer (score 1):

Use **"DataGridViewRow"** ao invés de "DataRow" para poder ir precisamente ao valor que você precisa... **Cells(0)** quer dizer que o valor que você quer está na coluna 0... Se for na coluna 1, então use **Cells(1)** e assim por diante. O código abaixo é pra dar certo

```
  Public Shared Function GetNextDiaUtil(d As Date) As Date
            Dim feriados As DataTable = ManipulaDB.ConsultaSql("SELECT CAMPO2 FROM TAB_FERIADOS")
            If d.DaysOfWeek = DaysOfWeek.Saturday Then
                d = d.AddDays(2)
            ElseIf d.DayOfWeek = DaysOfWeek.Sunday Then
                d = d.AddDays(1)
            End If

            For Each data As DataGridViewRow In feriados.Rows
                If d = CDate(data.Cells(0).Value) Then
                    d = d.AddDays(1)
                End If
            Next
        Return d
    End Function
```